# Como usar en devc++ el cout y cin?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Recien empiezo programacion en la universidad. He intentado con fstream.h, iostream.h y ninguno permite el dev. Y si por si se preguntan si lo guarde el codigo como c++

Comment: Hola andres HM puedes porfavor poner tu codigo ?

Comment: Has probado a escribir `using namespace std;`?
Porque si no lo has puesto para usar cout y cin deberás escribir `std::cout <<` o `std::cin >>`

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias agregar el codigo que tenes?

Comment: `<iostream.h>` se usaba antes de la estandarización de C++ y es probablemente la razón por la que devc++ no lo reconozca. En su lugar se debe usar `<iostream>`.

Comment: (Xam) con iostream todo chevere pero no entiendo porque no con el fstream.

Comment: (Arukaito) por ejemplo este, 
# include <fstream.h>
#include <conio.h>
  void main ( )
  { char nombre[30];
   cout<< “ digite su nombre \n ”;
   cin>>nombre;
   clrscr ( );
   gotoxy(27,12);
   cout<< “ HOLA,”<<“   ”<<nombre;     
   getch ( );     }
en el DEV muere

Comment: @AndrésHM `<fstream>` es para trabajar con archivos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usa estas librerías básica

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

// y luego no te olvides de

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: ¿Para qué son necesarias `conio` y `stdlib` exactamente? Me refiero a la hora de usar `cin` y `cout`. Tampoco veo claro que usar `using namespace` sea algo imprescindible... de hecho yo apenas lo uso y mis programas en C++ funcionan sin problemas.